# File vs uchardet

Tags: shell-script

Which command is more reliable for scripting text encoding conversion ?

I'm currently using file but I'd like to be sure before running it on all my text files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` is better in binaries, `uchardet` is better in text files. For example file doesn't know Windows-1250.

Comment: But how do you know uchardet is better for text files? For me they seem to always give different results...file often thinks it's a iso-8859-1 and uchardet think it's windows-1252

Comment: I was looking at file's db: There are just rules for unicode.

Answer (score 1):

[`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) is a good tool to [identify, or rather, guess encoding](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file).

You can use [`iconv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) to change encoding. [Full answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 < input.txt > output.txt
```